# Using managedwriter without a protocol definition

Tags: go, google-bigquery, google-bigquery-storage-api

I am trying to use [Go BigQuery Storage API Client](https://pkg.go.dev/cloud.google.com/go/bigquery/storage/managedwriter). I checked that data can be inserted for most field types. However, preparing the protocol buffers definition isn't enjoyable every time I insert data. Java client has [JsonStreamWriter](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/write-api-streaming) class; it seems very useful.

Is there a way to insert data without a protocol buffers definition using Go client as Java client?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `adapt` subpackage of `managedwriter` [includes functionality to convert a schema into a descriptor representation](https://pkg.go.dev/cloud.google.com/go/bigquery/storage/managedwriter/adapt#StorageSchemaToProto2Descriptor).

That, coupled with https://pkg.go.dev/google.golang.org/protobuf/encoding/protojson should make it reasonable to use JSON as an intermediate format.  There's an [integration test](https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-go/blob/c65fd1b48dc58047c74d349b24259189c5b29773/bigquery/storage/managedwriter/integration_test.go#L247) in managedwriter that demonstrates this as well.

If you want to share more details about your specific conversion needs, please [open an issue](https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-go/issues) on the google-cloud-go repo with additional details.

Comment: If I want to encode own struct, I have to encode to JSON first, right?